# c# string[] to jquery string list?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

tried using the following but it's not the solution

controller:

```
var list = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };
ViewData["List"] = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(list);
```

jquery:

```
var list = [ '@ViewData["List"]' ];
$("#numbers").autocomplete({
    source: list
});
```

Comment: no such thing as jquery string list... check the server output for `"var list = ..."` in view source in the browser

Comment: it's ['[&quot;one&quot;,&quot;two&quot;,&quot;three&quot;]'];

Comment: To make a javascript array on the client side, the output needs to be `"["one", "two", "three"]"`

Comment: I realize that, but the javascript serializer didn't output that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your page (presumably razor, based on your syntax), declare your list as so:

```
var list = @Html.Raw(ViewData["List"]);
```

In your current implementation the HtmlHelper is encoding your string to display correctly in a webpage, which you obviously do not want (hence the use of HtmlHelper.Raw) and you are also nesting an array within an array.

Comment: That gave me the following one big long string using the javascript serializer['["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"]'];

Comment: Was that not what you expected?

Comment: I figured it out, I had added it as such var list = ['@ViewData... Your example worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var list = [ '@Html.Raw(ViewData["List"])' ];
$("#numbers").autocomplete({
    source: list
});
```